# How to change KryoSerializer to pojoSerializer with state compatible？

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Java class where some fields do not have getter and setter methods, so this class uses a kryo serializer. Subsequently, I added the get and set methods to the class. Afterwards, I started the job from savepoint, but it couldn't be started. The error is as follows:
org.apache.flink.util.StateMigrationException: The new state serializer (org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.MapSerializer@a14d4dc5) must not be incompatible with the old state serializer (org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.MapSerializer@1d44e08b).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqx3v.png)

I found that Kryo is not compatible with other serializers. Is there any way to solve this problem

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/zh/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/serialization/custom_serialization/
I found the article above, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://docs.immerok.cloud/docs/how-to-guides/development/migrating-state-away-from-kryo/ describes how to migrate state away from Kryo using the state processor API. That article points to [a reference implementation on github](https://github.com/immerok/recipes/tree/main/kryo-migration).

Comment: Hey, I am having similar problem but i am using flink SQL to query converted from datstream.